# Nuxt redirect is making state null when middleware is checking routes

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, middleware

Here I have the code in my Nuxt middleware. The code works fine till I use the redirect function. As soon as I use redirect inside route checker if condition. It says the user is null.
In this image you can see in the console in client.js it shows User with all data but below that immediately it show User null in handle-login-route.js which is my middleware due to which redirect is not working.
[image]

Here is my middleware code

```
export default function ({ store, route, redirect}) {
  const user = store.getters["user/user"];
  const blockRouteAdmin = /\/admin\/*/g;
  const blockRouteManager = /\/manager\/*/g;
  const path = ["/signup", "/login"];
  let value = path.includes(route.path);
  console.log("User", user);
  if (user) {
    if (user.isAdmin) {
      if (!route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin)) {
        redirect("/admin");
      }
    }
    if (user.isManager) {
      if (!route.path.match(blockRouteManager)) {
        redirect("/manager");
      }
    }
    if (user.isUser) {
      if (
        route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin) ||
        route.path.match(blockRouteManager) ||
        value
      ) {
        redirect("/");
      }
    }
  }
  if (!user) {
    console.log("No user");
    if (
      route.path.match(blockRouteAdmin) ||
      route.path.match(blockRouteManager)
    ) {
      redirect("/");
    } else {
      redirect();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried add return false after redirect, and rewrite condition if (user) ... if (!user) with  if (user) .... else  ?

Comment: Yes I tried its not working. I don't know what's the problem. The same code worked with my previous projects. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Why dont you use redirect function of nuxt to change route ? exp :  this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })

Comment: I tried using it. But the keywords like this and window are not available in middleware. I console logged this keyword and it was undefined. So the only option I am left with is redirect. I also tried using app.router.push('/admin') to access Nuxt router, but that's not working.